# Show the saving amount for on sale products in WooCommerce single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, product-variations

I'm using the following code to display the percent discount for simple and variable products, which works fine:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'bbloomer_show_sale_percentage_loop', 25 );

function bbloomer_show_sale_percentage_loop() {

  global $product;

  if ( !$product->is_on_sale() ) return;

  if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {

    $max_percentage = ( ( $product->get_regular_price() - $product->get_sale_price() ) / $product->get_regular_price() ) * 100;

  } elseif ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {

    $max_percentage = 0;

    foreach ( $product->get_children() as $child_id ) {

      $variation = wc_get_product( $child_id );

      $price = $variation->get_regular_price();

      $sale = $variation->get_sale_price();

      if ( $price != 0 && !empty( $sale ) )$percentage = ( $price - $sale ) / $price * 100;

      if ( $percentage > $max_percentage ) {

        $max_percentage = $percentage;

      }

    }

  }

  if ( $max_percentage > 0 )echo "<p class='sale-perc'>" . round( $max_percentage ) . "%   Discount</p>";
}
```

How to call in template pages:

```
 <?php bbloomer_show_sale_percentage_loop(); ?>
```

Now I want to calculate the amount of the discount to show the customer the benefit of buying that product.

I found a code to achieve this, but this code has two main problems:

First: It only applies to simple products.

Second: by adding this code to the functions.php file, the WooCommerce payment page will crash.

Is there a better code or solution for this so that I can calculate and show the customer profit for all WooCommerce products (simple and variable)?

The code to show the customer's profit from buying a simple product:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'simple_product_saving_amount', 11 );
function simple_product_saving_amount() {
    global $product;
    if( $product->is_type('simple') && $product->is_on_sale() ) {
        $regular_price = (float) wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array('price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) );
        $active_price  = (float) wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array('price' => $product->get_sale_price() ) );
        $saved_amount  = $regular_price - $active_price;
        echo '<p id=&quotsaving_total_price&quot>'. __(&quot your profit &quot) .': ' . wc_price($saved_amount) . ' </p>';}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is the multiple `&quot` that should be instead replaced by `"` in the last line inside your function.

So the right working code for simple products on single product pages:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'simple_product_saving_amount', 11 );
function simple_product_saving_amount() {
    global $product;

    if( $product->is_type('simple') && $product->is_on_sale() ) {
        $args = array( 'price' => $product->get_regular_price() );
        if ( 'incl' === get_option('woocommerce_tax_display_shop') ) {
            $regular_price = wc_get_price_including_tax( $product, $args );
            $active_price  = wc_get_price_including_tax( $product );
        } else {
            $regular_price = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product, $args );
            $active_price  = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product );
        }
        $saved_amount  = $regular_price - $active_price;
        printf( '<p id="saving_total_price">%s %s</p>', __('Your profit:'), wc_price( $saved_amount ) );
    }
}
```

Now for product variations in single variable product pages you will use:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'product_variation_saving_amount', 10, 3 );
function product_variation_saving_amount( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {
    if ( $variation->is_on_sale() ) {
        $args = array( 'price' => $variation->get_regular_price() );
        if ( 'incl' === get_option('woocommerce_tax_display_shop') ) {
            $regular_price = wc_get_price_including_tax( $variation, $args );
            $active_price  = wc_get_price_including_tax( $variation );
        } else {
            $regular_price = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $variation, $args );
            $active_price  = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $variation );
        }

        $saving_html   = sprintf( '<p id="saving_total_price">%s %s</p>', __('Your profit:'), 
            wc_price($regular_price - $active_price) );
        
            $variation_data['price_html'] .= '<br>' . $saving_html;
    }
    return $variation_data;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Hello. I want to use this code on the checkout page. For this purpose, the short code `<?php product_variation_saving_amount(); ?>` to the payment page but the page still crashed. Is there a problem with the shortcode I used or should I not use it on the WooCommerce checkout page?

Comment: Also, for the first code of the short code `<?php simple_product_saving_amount(); ?>`  I used it and the payment page crashed again.

Comment: You can't use that on checkout page, it's not made for that, and you didn't ask in your question to have something for checkout. You just said that the code was making the checkout page crashing. So your question is not clear and you don't provide any details on where and how you want to display the saving on checkout page…

Comment: Yes, I realized that I did not ask my question correctly. For the variable product, what **shortcode** should I use to display it on the **single-product** page?

Comment: And is it possible for you to provide me with a piece of code to check all the products on the payment page and calculate the percent discount of all the products and then display it to the customer? Just like the codes above, only for the **payment page**.

Comment: You can not use a shortcode on variable products single pages, as you can NOT get the "live" *selected* variation, with it, to display the saving for that selected variation. When asking a question, if you want a shortcode, say it and specify where exactly and how you are going to use it. Now for cart / checkout saving total, you should better ask a new question, trying to find before some related code, making your own code attempt...

Comment: I created another question and in it I am only looking for a code to check all the products and collect the products that have a discount and show them to the customer as a profit. Question link: [Calculating the discount percentage on the WooCommerce payment page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76546897/calculating-the-discount-percentage-on-the-woocommerce-payment-page)

Comment: I have, updated my code, in a better way that handle WooCommerce price settings display.