# Create a conditional command to customize the selection

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a section for my template in the customization section using the **select** controller so that the user can choose one of several texts to display on the page.

The code in the customization section works fine, but I want to click on each option to show the text I set for it, and hide the rest.

**In summary:**
If the user selects **`teb2`**, the **`.txt_one`** class will be displayed and the rest of the classes will be `display: none`.

And for the rest of the selection controller options, it should be the same.

I have put a code in the `functions.php` file to create customization with the selection controller:

```
function edite_add_select($wp_customize){
 
    //add section
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'edite_select_section', array(
 
                'title' => 'Select text',
                'priority' => 10,
                'description' => 'Select the text you want' 
 
    ));
 
    //add setting
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'edite_select', array(
                'default' => 'teb1',  
    ));
 
    //add control
    $wp_customize->add_control( 'edite_select_control', array(
                'label' => 'Change the default text',
                'type'  => 'select', 
                'section' => 'edite_select_section',
                'settings' => 'edite_select',
                'choices' => array(
                'teb1' => 'default',
                'teb2' => 'text2',
    )
    ));
 
}
 
add_action( 'customize_register', 'edite_add_select' );
```

The code I put on the page in question:

```
<div>
<h2 id="text_title">Display text</h2>
    <p class="txt_default">text default</p>
    <p class="txt_one">text one</p>
</div>
```

---

**Edite:**

In order for you to better understand what I mean, I created this conditional code and now I just want this code to react according to the selection of the option in the **selection controller**:

```
 function display_element() {
     
            $i = 'teb1';
            while ( have_posts() ) {
                
                if(($i = 'teb1' ) == 'default') { ?>

                    <style type="text/css">
                      
                        .txt_default{
                            display: block;
                        }
                        
                        .txt_one{
                            display: none;
                        }
                    </style>
                    <?php 
                }
                else{ ?>
                    <style type="text/css">
                      .txt_default{
                            display: none;
                        }
                        
                        .txt_one{
                            display: block;
                        }
                    </style>
                    <?php
                }
            } 
     
     
            $y = 'teb2';
            while ( have_posts() ) {
                
                if(($y = 'teb2' ) == 'text2') { ?>

                    <style type="text/css">
                      
                        .txt_default{
                            display: none;
                        }
                        
                        .txt_one{
                            display: block;
                        }
                    </style>
                    <?php 
                }
                else{ ?>
                    <style type="text/css">
                      .txt_default{
                            display: block;
                        }
                        
                        .txt_one{
                            display: none;
                        }
                    </style>
                    <?php
                }
            } 
 }
```