# Change "Total" text in WooCommerce cart and checkout pages

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart, checkout, gettext

WooCommerce uses [`wc_cart_totals_order_total_html()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/7.8/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart-totals.php#L99) function to display the "formatted order total amount *(including tax if needed)*" in cart page *(and checkout too)*.

In the cart page (and checkout), I would like to be able to add the text "**Amount to be paid:**" next to the displayed total amount.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: hi. The short code I used only displays the total amount, but I want it to be printed along with the sentence (**amount to be paid:**). For this purpose, create a function in the `functions.php` file and use the short code that I put to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To alter, the text "Total" displayed next to the formatted displayed total amount (in cart and checkout pages), you can use a custom function hooked in WordPress `gettext` hook as follows:

```php
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_some_woocommerce_strings', 10, 3 );
function change_some_woocommerce_strings( $translate_text, $original_text, $domain ) {
    if ( $original_text === 'Total' && $domain === 'woocommerce' && ( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) ) {
        $translate_text = __('Amount to be paid', $domain);
    }

    return $translate_text;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.